# How to detect Circle Menu's animation has finished in android?

Tags: android, menu

Im using [CircleMenu](https://github.com/Hitomis/CircleMenu)
Layout

```
<com.hitomi.cmlibrary.CircleMenu
    android:id="@+id/circle_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Activity

```
circleMenu = (CircleMenu) findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);

circleMenu.setMainMenu(Color.parseColor("#CDCDCD"), R.mipmap.icon_menu, R.mipmap.icon_cancel)
        .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#258CFF"), R.mipmap.icon_home)
        .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#30A400"), R.mipmap.icon_search)
        .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF4B32"), R.mipmap.icon_notify)
        .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#8A39FF"), R.mipmap.icon_setting)
        .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.icon_gps)
        .setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMenuSelected(int index) {
                  switch (i){
                         case  0:

                       ((SomeScreenSlidePagerActivity)getActivity()).refresh();

                             break;
                         case 1:

                           ((SomeScreenSlidePagerActivity)getActivity()).logout();


                             break;
                         case 2:

                               ((SomeScreenSlidePagerActivity)getActivity()).showNotifications();
                             break;

                         default:
                             break;
                     }
            }

        });
```

When i press on a subMenu button animation starts but it finishes, OnMenuSelected option executes so it looks very bad. i want  animation to finish then start executing OnMenuSelected option. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addListener()` of `Animation` of the class `CircleMenu.java`